# Is there a way to have form to be on the top layer without using iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Right now I am using iFrame for the questions but is there a better way for it?

Clicking on the "ülesanne" brings the iFrame to top. 
http://www.tlu.ee/~kristo93/Eritamine%20-%20puhas/p6hi3.html

I am using KineticJs library for layering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `z-index` css property to a **high** value like- For example- setting `z-index:999;` i.e. to a high value makes sure that the element remains at the top of the other Dom elements(The idea is to make the `z-index` higher than that the other elements might have).

You may use the `display:none;` and `display:block;` css properties to toggle the visibility , and make sure z-index only works on positioned elements `(position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)` .